Pre-1990 movie about two teenage boys' secret relationship
When I was around 12 years old (1990), I saw on VCR a movie that caught my attention. Two years later I watched it again, but sadly lost the cassette since then. But, I remember some details that might help identify the movie.

The movie takes place inside a school, with teenagers (who appeared to be 14-18) and teachers.
The school has a choir. At first I assumed it was church boys; however, later (since the question was deleted) I searched around and most likely it was an "ordinary" choir, unrelated to church.
Two of the boys in the choir fall in love, and the movie is about them and how their relationship is developing.
They hide their relationship, as it's apparent such a thing is not acceptable in the school.
There was at least one explicit scene showing them together in a bed.
At some point they are caught by a teacher, and either get some punishment or are expelled from school.
The movie ends showing them sailing away in a boat.
The movie was around one hour long and either non-English or with some strong non-US accent, e.g. British.
Based on the general appearance of what I remember, the movie might have been filmed even before 1970 (and up to 1990).

Can anyone identify this? Here is a list of suggestions that I already looked into, and it's not what I saw:

You Are Not Alone (1978)
Heaven Help Us
Two of Us (1987 BBC TV Movie)
Au revoir les enfants


Are they "church boys" or do they just go to a private/religious school? Could you be thinking of Get Real?

@AbbyT I think they were church boys, as there was that chorus with all the boys in it - isn't it just for church boys? Anyway, it can't be Get Real, the movie is way too new. I'll edit to make it more clear.

Is in any way similar to The Name of the Rose

@e-MEE not really - no death, no abbey, no priests..

@iandotkelly thanks for bringing this question back. Please let me know when the identification tags would be available again, so I can put back the proper tag.

To some of us, ‘British’ is not a “heavy accent”!  (Not from some parts of Britain, anyway…)  It would help to clarify what sort of accent the question is ruling out.

@gidds ah, sorry about that. I couldn't find a good way to edit, but essentially I'm ruling out any language that does not sound like American English at all. When I watched the movie I was used to hear only American English so I remember the language there was different. If you can suggest an edit to my question is would be great, and I'll approve it.

The movie that best fits your description is You Are Not Alone (1978)

A student strike at a Danish boys school is the backdrop of YOU ARE
  NOT ALONE. The leisurely paced tale explores the relationship between
  15-year-old Bo and Kim, the younger son of the stern boarding school
  headmaster. Mounting school tensions over the expulsion of a troubled
  student threaten to sabotage the tranquility of the school.


+1 for your efforts but I fear still no luck - the story/plot might fit but those are not the characters I saw. Also, I'm sure there was boy chorus so it wasn't ordinary boarding school.

One more crack at this:
After finding a half-decent synopsis, this movie seems to fit all of your remembered details:
You Are Not Alone (1978) 

This had actually already been proposed by another user, but had been deleted (don't know why).

Ah, I wasn't sure if that had been the one which disappeared.  Important to keep the incorrect guesses around until the questions is resolved at least, I would think.

@Christian is correct it was already posted - however it's not what I saw.

@mootinator Yes of course. I'm glad it's there again and wondered why the other answerer deleted it, since it sounded quite appropriate. But well, it doesn't seem to be the correct answer, but at least now nobody else will post it again.

As this is the closest to what I saw, you got the bounty. :)

My best guess would have to be Two of Us (1987 BBC TV Movie)
Wikipedia
It's British, seems to take place in/around a school, targeted at teenagers so nothing raunchy.  Dropped out could conceivably be remembered as expelled. I just don't know where the church part would come in.

No, sorry.. saw some pictures and they don't fit to what I remember.

I’m having another go at this. Could it be The Devil’s Playground (1976)?
This is an Australian movie that fits a lot of the plot points you have cited. It’s a coming-of-age drama set in a Catholic school. There’s an emotional relationship between characters of the same age that you remember.
It’s not a big-budget production, but it was critically well-received and would have been considered mainstream enough to have had a VHS release, and to have remained available at the time you remember watching it.
It won the 1976 Australian Film Institute Award for Best Film, Best Direction, Best Lead Actor, Best Screenplay, Best Achievement in Cinematography, and the Jury Prize. It has a 100% score on Rotten Tomatoes.
Even if it isn’t the film you’re thinking of, it’s a good movie, and it sounds similar enough that you should enjoy it.

Looks like a good movie indeed, but I'm afraid still not what I've seen. Thanks!

It’s becoming clear that there is an underappreciated genre of  forbidden-relationship-in-catholic-school movies.

Totally agree, though I stumbled upon that movie by chance, and that led my later to appreciate such movies.

Maybe Au revoir les enfants, though a French movie.

No, thanks for trying though. :)

Please add a description on why you think this is the answer.  Answers containing links only without explanation are not allowed globally on SE.

Was it This Special Friendship (Les amitiés particulières)?
It’s about an intimate relationship between two boys at a Roman Catholic boarding school. It’s based on a novel by Roger Peyrefitte of the same name, and shares a lot of plot points with the film you’re describing.
I don’t remember there being an explicit scene in it, but maybe I watched a TV edit.

Thanks. Good answer, and indeed lots of similar things, but after watching this trailer, I'm afraid that's not it. They looked different.
